# Ignore content type for specific WCF OperationContracts

Tags: wcf, json.net, wcf-rest

I have a WCF REST Service that primarily sends and receives JSON.

In general, I'm okay with using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`, but for some objects that are passed in as parameters to the OperationContact methods, I need to use JSON.NET for the deserialization.

To do this, the standard approach is to have a `Stream` as an input parameter.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "DoStuff", Method = "POST",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public void SetAppSettings(Stream input)
{
    // parse input as JSON string, deserialize, process
}
```

However, when I try to POST content with `Content-Type: application/json` to this method, I get an exception saying that Raw content was expected.

From the point of view of the client, I am *always* sending `application/json` content. I don't want  the client to have be aware that it should be setting `Content-Type: text/plain` instead of `application/json` (which is used in every other case).

Is there a way to get WCF to ignore the request content type *for specific OperationContracts* (rather than switching to a raw model for the entire service)?

Alternatively, is there some way I could omit the `Stream` parameter, and instead get the raw bytes of the request body from, say, `HttpContext.Current` while inside the method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly setting the request format at the operation contract level?

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "DoStuff", Method = "POST",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
           **RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json**)]
public void SetAppSettings(Stream input)
{
    // parse input as JSON string, deserialize, process
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem as the person who asked the question and this didn't work for me.